# EBS not showing correct disk size in amazon web service

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a new xtra large EC2 machine with 300 GB EBS volume attached to the root

When the instance properties are viewed in the EC2 panel it shows 
`Root Device: /dev/sda1` which is connected to an `EBS ID` correponding to an `EBS volume` with capacity `300GB`

but df -h shows the size to be 50 GB

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              50G   18G   30G  38% /
none                  7.5G  3.6G  4.0G  48% /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to resize the filesytem. Depending on what filesystem type you need to use a specific command. For example for ext2, ext3, ext4 you can use resizefs.  You can find more information about it here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html